# Haskell и Монады

Tags: io, haskell

При воспроизведении данного куска кода:

```
half x = if even x
           then Just (x `div` 2)
           else Nothing

printMaybe m = case m of
  Nothing -> putStrLn "List was empty!"
  Just x -> print x

main = do
  let halfN = Just 4 >>= half
  halfN >>= printMaybe
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
main.hs:9:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `Maybe ()'
    * In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action `main'
  |
9 | main = do
  | ^
main.hs:11:13: error:
    * Couldn't match type `IO' with `Maybe'
      Expected type: Maybe a0 -> Maybe ()
        Actual type: Maybe a0 -> IO ()
    * In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `printMaybe'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: halfN >>= printMaybe
      In the expression:
        do let halfN = Just 4 >>= half
           halfN >>= printMaybe
   |
11 |   halfN >>= printMaybe
```

Вот способ решения этой проблемы:

```
half x = if even x
           then Just (x `div` 2)
           else Nothing

printMaybe m = case m of
  Nothing -> putStrLn "List was empty!"
  Just x -> print x

main = do
  let halfN = Just 4 >>= half
  printMaybe $ halfN
```

Не могу понять, почему изначальная программа не работает. Сначала получаем половину числа в функции `half` (в виде монады `Maybe`), после чего "пропихиваем" это значение в функцию вывода - `printMaybe`.

Почему первоначальная версия кода не работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>=` это оператор не "пропихивания", а монадического связывания

```hs
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

И связывает он, как видно из сигнатуры, только однотипные контейнеры `Maybe` с `Maybe`, `IO` с `IO` и т.д.
Вы же пытаетесь связать

```hs
halfN :: Integral a => Maybe a
```

и

```hs
printMaybe :: Show a => Maybe a -> IO ()
```

Т.е. контейнеры разных типов - `Maybe` и `IO`, и с несовместимыми типами содержимого `Integral a => a` против `Show a => Maybe a`.

```hs
printMaybe $ halfN
```

Это правильный способ использования этой функции, альтернативой (эквивалентной по первому закону монад, но совершенно неуместной в данном случае) может быть

```hs
return halfN >>= printMaybe
```

То же касается и `Just 4 >>= half`, лучше заменить это на `half 4` потому, что для `Monad Maybe`

```hs
return = Just
```

Примеры правильного использования

```hs
*Main> half 12
Just 6
*Main> half 12 >>= half
Just 3
*Main> [1..3] >>= show
"123"
*Main> [1..3] >>= \x -> replicate x x
[1,2,2,3,3,3]
*Main> getLine >>= print -- далее ввод с клавиатуры
12
"12"
*Main> getLine >>= \x -> print (half (read x)) -- далее ввод с клавиатуры
12
Just 6
```

И еще один момент: не забывайте указывать сигнатуры функций, это упростит вам понимание того, что у вас получилось (или не получилось)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ!) То есть для того, чтобы можно было использовать оператор монадического связывания `>>=`, нужно, чтобы контейнеры были одного типа (тип возвращаемого значения функции, в данном случае printMaybe, должен совпадать с типом монады, которая подана на вход, halfN в этом контексте)? Играет ли роль несовместимости типа содержимого? Остался не совсем понятным данный момент.

Comment: Функция справа принимает содержимое контейнера слева. У вас, помимо того что контейнеры разных типов, в левом - число, а функция хочет что-то упакованное в `Maybe`. Вот об этой несовместимости речь. Добавил пару примеров использования.